# Colorizing certain part of the text in JEditorPane makes foreground colorization fail

Tags: java, swing, jeditorpane

I want to use a JEditorPane to show some text in a certain color (say green) as and when the user enter the text, and to change the color of some parts (Eg: 0th to 9th characters red) once certain conditions are met.

So basically, I need a default foreground color, and need to change some parts of the text's color on the fly. My attempt so far has been the following. However, the setForeground() method doesn't seem to fix the problem. How would I solve this? Using something like a JTextPane is unfortunately not an option because of some issues in JTextPane that makes it unsuitable for what I'm working on. Thanks!

SSCCE:

```
 public class ColoredStrikeThroughText {
    public ColoredStrikeThroughText() {
        JFrame fr = new JFrame("Custom color attribute");

        fr.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JEditorPane pane = new JEditorPane();

        pane.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
        pane.setEditorKit(new StyledEditorKit() {
            public ViewFactory getViewFactory() {
                return new NewViewFactory();

            }
        });

        pane.setText("Color red text, color blue text, text without coloring.");

        StyledDocument doc = (StyledDocument) pane.getDocument();
        MutableAttributeSet attr = new SimpleAttributeSet();

        StyleContext sc = StyleContext.getDefaultStyleContext();
        AttributeSet aset = sc.addAttribute(SimpleAttributeSet.EMPTY, StyleConstants.Foreground, Color.red);

        attr.addAttributes(aset);

        doc.setCharacterAttributes(0, 9, attr, false);

        aset = sc.addAttribute(SimpleAttributeSet.EMPTY, StyleConstants.Foreground, Color.blue);
        attr.addAttributes(aset);
        doc.setCharacterAttributes(17, 27, attr, false);
        JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(pane);

        fr.getContentPane().add(sp);
        fr.setSize(300, 300);
        fr.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        fr.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ColoredStrikeThroughText test = new ColoredStrikeThroughText();
    }
}

class NewViewFactory implements ViewFactory {
    public View create(Element elem) {
        String kind = elem.getName();
        if (kind != null) {
            if (kind.equals(AbstractDocument.ContentElementName)) {
                return new LabelView(elem);
            } else if (kind.equals(AbstractDocument.ParagraphElementName)) {
                return new ParagraphView(elem);
            } else if (kind.equals(AbstractDocument.SectionElementName)) {
                return new BoxView(elem, View.Y_AXIS);
            } else if (kind.equals(StyleConstants.ComponentElementName)) {
                return new ComponentView(elem);
            } else if (kind.equals(StyleConstants.IconElementName)) {
                return new IconView(elem);
            }
        }
        // default to text display
        return new LabelView(elem);
    }
}

class MyLabelView extends LabelView {

    public MyLabelView(Element elem) {
        super(elem);
    }


}
```

EDIT 1:

Thank you all. I'm afraid that my question didn't clarify a few things. I had left these things out as I feared that the question might become too long, but I'll post them here since there seems to be no other way to clarify:

1) Why I'm not using a JTextPane. The reason is beacause word wrapping fails to work when I use it as follows:

SSCCE:

```
public class nowrapsscce extends JPanel{
    public  nowrapsscce() {

        JFrame j = new JFrame();

            JEditorPane inputPane = new JEditorPane(); //replace JEditorPane with 
//JTextPane here to see how word wrapping fails

        inputPane.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        inputPane.setForeground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        inputPane.setCaretColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);

        JEditorPane noninputPane = new JEditorPane();

        noninputPane.setEditable(false);
        noninputPane.setText("Test ");
        noninputPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40, 200));

        noninputPane.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        noninputPane.setForeground(Color.BLACK);

        JPanel promptInputPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
        c.weighty = 1.0;
        c.weightx = 0;
        promptInputPanel.add(noninputPane, c);

        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
        c.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        c.weightx = 1.0;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        promptInputPanel.add(inputPane, c);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setBorder(new EtchedBorder());

        scrollPane.setViewportView(promptInputPanel);
        scrollPane
                .setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

        j.add(scrollPane);
        j.setVisible(true);
        j.pack();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        nowrapsscce test = new nowrapsscce();
    }
}
```

2) I can't make all the text white before colouring in certain parts of it because I want the user to enter text, and for the entire text to appear white by default, as it does in the SSCCE. Having a keylistener and entire a white character character-by-character would probably be too inefficient. I want to basically colourize certain words if they match a given word, but with this new, uneditable JTextPane / JEditorPane at the side, as in the SSCCE, which is the twist to the problem.

Thanks again :)

Comment: there are two ways 1. use Highlighter, note Highlighter is array, 2 StyleConstants in ParagraphAttributes for Object

Comment: @mKorbel `Highlighter` only changes background color, not foreground.

Comment: @user1803551 you have an access from Highlighter to StyleConstants, derived from (Mutable)AttributeSet, (ViewFactory by StanislavL??? is probablby for HtmlEditorKit)

Comment: You are changing the color correctly. I don't see where the problem is nor what is the condition for changing or attempt at changing the color on the fly.

Comment: By the way, you can use `switch` on `String kind` instead of all the `if else`.

Comment: Can you share the problem that you are facing with JTextPane. because it works perfectly with JTextPane.

Comment: JTextPane is subclass of  JEditorPane.

Comment: Have a look at my post.

Comment: Call `pack` before `setVisible`.

Comment: "I want to basically colourize certain words if they match a given word" Do they have to be in the same position in their respective editor panes, or is there just a list of words you want to color?

Comment: @user1803551 : No. I'm afraid the position may vary... It's a list that I want to colour, irrespective of where they may occur. The code that I wrote was just a demo of the problem I'm facing.

Answer (score 3):

**Workaround:** Setting foreground color for whole text before doing any custom coloring will solve your problem with `JEditorPane`

```
AttributeSet aset = sc.addAttribute(SimpleAttributeSet.EMPTY, 
                                     StyleConstants.Foreground,Color.GREEN);
attr.addAttributes(aset);
// set foreground for all the text
doc.setCharacterAttributes(0, pane.getText().length(), attr, false);
```

---

If you can choose `JTextPane` instead of `JEditorPane` then it will solve the issue.

Screenshot:

[image]

---

**EDIT**

> Why I'm not using a `JTextPane`. The reason is beacause word wrapping fails to work when I use it?

Here is the custom `JTextPane` class. You can try this class to solve wrapping issue.

Sample code:

```
public class NonWrappingTextPane extends JTextPane {
    public NonWrappingTextPane() {
        super();
    }

    public NonWrappingTextPane(StyledDocument doc) {
        super(doc);
    }

    // Override getScrollableTracksViewportWidth
    // to preserve the full width of the text
    public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportWidth() {
        Container parent = getParent();
        ComponentUI ui = getUI();

        return parent != null ? (ui.getPreferredSize(this).width <= parent.getSize().width) : true;
    }
}
```

Find complete code here [Non Wrapping(Wrap) TextPane](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/NonWrappingWrapTextPane.htm)

screenshot:

[image]

Comment: +1, I find working with a text pane (and styled text) is easier then using a JEditorPane (and HTML).

Comment: @Braj : Thank you :)
I have updated my question, adding al the info you asked for.
Thanks again :D

Comment: @Braj : I'm afraid the custom class doesn't work, neither in the application nor in the SSCCE :(

Answer (score 1):

This will color occurrences of specified words with their specified respective colors:

```
public class Colorer extends JFrame {

    Pattern pat;
    Map<String, SimpleAttributeSet> map = new HashMap<>();
    JEditorPane editor = new JEditorPane();

    public Colorer() {

        String[] words = {"atext1", "atext", "text1"};
        Color[] colors = {Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE};
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); // You can use words.length*8 in the constructor argument to estimate the capacity.
        for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            sb.append("("+words[i]+")" + "|");
            SimpleAttributeSet sas = new SimpleAttributeSet();
            StyleConstants.setForeground(sas, colors[i]);
            map.put(words[i], sas);
        }
        sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length()-1);
        pat = Pattern.compile(sb.toString());

        editor.setEditorKit(new StyledEditorKit());
        editor.setDocument(new DefaultStyledDocument());
        editor.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new ColorDocumentLister());

        getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(editor));
        pack();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private class ColorDocumentLister implements DocumentListener {

        SimpleAttributeSet black = new SimpleAttributeSet();

        ColorDocumentLister() {

            StyleConstants.setForeground(black, Color.BLACK);
        }

        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {

            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {

                    finaAndColor();
                }
            });
        }

        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {

            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {

                    finaAndColor();
                }
            });
        }

        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {

        }

        private void finaAndColor() {

            StyledDocument doc = (StyledDocument) editor.getDocument();
            doc.setCharacterAttributes(0, doc.getLength(), black, true);

            Matcher m = pat.matcher(editor.getText());
            while (m.find()) {
                doc.setCharacterAttributes(m.start(), m.end(), map.get(m.group()), true);
                doc.setCharacterAttributes(m.end(), doc.getLength(), black, true);
            }   
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new Colorer();
    }
}
```

**Notes:**

- This is probably *not* the right way to achieve this functionality, but that's what I can offer currently.
- One problem is that with every addition or removal of text from the text editor a new string is created containing the entire content - very inefficient for large contents.
- Depending on the bigger picture (your end goal), you will need to modify this implementation for better performance, functionality, and design logic.